# how to find an object in an array react

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

so i am making a following / followers component in my react code and using redux to manage the state,
so lets say a user follows another user and my following model in my data base might look like this
users following model

```
following: [
{
_id: "1213231235t34",
user: "242545367675445666",
username: "john",
email: "john@d.com"
},
{
_id: "625675676552",
user: "876869897976566",
username: "lenon",
email: "john@d.com"
},
{
_id: "1213231235t34",
user: "34536655344365654",
username: "mike",
email: "john@d.com"
},
{
_id: "1213231235t34",
user: "FINDTHIS",
username: "crease",
email: "john@d.com"
}
]
```

### how can i find if the user(FIND THIS) is in the array and do something if it is found

for example the following model is like this when a user follows people

now if i go on the page of crease(THE LAST OBJECT IN THE ARRAY) i do not want to see a follow button, rather i want to see an unfollow button because he is already in my array of the users i am currently following.
so how can i loop through the array and find the field of user(FINDTHIS)for the crease object...
bascially i am asking how can i find if i am following crease... mind you i am using react so es6 syntax
if you could help that would be wonderful... THANKS!
if you do not understand the question please kindly ask for more info

Answer (score 0):

When I understood your question correctly this should help you:

```
const findSpecificUser = ArrayName.map((user) => {
    if(user.user === 'FINDTHIS'){
        //display or not display the ui elements
    }
})
```

Comment: yeah, thanks i just figured it out myself, such a noob question lmao, thanks anyways

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at the MDN Documentation for Array-Methods, as these kind of problems will occur more often.